# vector deep copy using a functor or lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda

I am trying to make deep copies of vectors of std::shared_ptr. Unfortunately I can't use objects, as most of those pointers are to polymorphic objects.

I've tried using the clone method adapted to std::shared_ptr:

```
std::shared_ptr<Action> Clone ( )
{
  return std::make_shared<Action>( *this );
}
```

But I am still running into problems.
So, I was wondering (can't remember where I've seen it) how can I copy the contents of one vector into another, by using a function or a lambda that performs the actual deep copy.

Let me rephrase, I don't want just the pointers, I want a copy of the pointed objects too.
The typical assignment

```
operator=
```

for std::vector appears to copy only the pointers as one would normally expect.

I'm using GCC 4.8 with C++11 in case it can offer any more elegant or minimalistic approach.

The actual purpose is so that copy constructors of classes that have those vectors, provide non-shared objects but same or different pointers:

```
class State
{
public:
  State ( const State & rhs )
  {
    // Deep copy Actions here?
  }


private:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Action>> _actions;
};
```

Many thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: `make_shared` shouldn't be given the result of `new`, just the constructor arguments.

Comment: right, yes, it may not catch an exception throw, ty

Comment: Your `Clone` method slices the object: it always creates an instance of `Action`, never a class derived from `Action`. Once you figure out how to clone one element, use `std::transform` to apply it to a vectorful of them.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, It shouldn't be if that `clone` function is in a derived class.

Comment: In this specific case its non-polymorphic class. I'm guessing normally I'd need a virtual function to do the cloning?

Comment: @chris: by what black magic is `make_shared<Action>` supposed to know that it's being called from inside a method of derived class?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Woops, my mistake.

Comment: @chris `make_shared<T>` will construct a `T`; you're thinking of the `shared_ptr` constructor that takes a pointer to an object of another type that is convertible to `T*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deep-copy/clone a type-erased type the cloning function needs to be virtual

```
struct Action {
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Action> clone() const =0;
};
struct Paste : public Action {  
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Action> clone() const 
    {return std::make_shared<Paste>(*this);}
};
```

Once you have that, then you can use `transform` and a simple lambda.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Action>> ActionList = {...};

auto cloner = [](const std::shared_ptr<Action>& ptr) 
    -> std::shared_ptr<Action> 
    {return ptr->clone();};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Action>> Copy;
std::transform(ActionList.begin(), ActionList.end(), std::back_inserter(Copy), cloner);
```

Comment: 1) Does it have to be pure virtual, or can I simply make it virtual and override it in the inheriting class ?
2) In case of a non-polymorphic class, calling the copy constructor in the lambda would suffice?

Comment: `Copy` is supposed to derive from `Action`, I presume?

Comment: @Alex: It doesn't have to be pure virtual, the important part is overriding it.  In the case of a non-polymorphic class, yes, the copy constructor suffices. Igor: Yes >.<