# Can a container of pointers be deep copied without explicity iterating over every element?

Tags: c++, pointers, copy, deep-copy

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969260/stdshared-ptr-deep-copy-object) nicely addresses the deep copy of a pointer (in this case a smart pointer type), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073528/c-deep-copy-vector-pointer-object) addresses the deep copy of a container with a for loop.

Is there a way to perform the deep copy of the container without explicitly iterating over every element?

For example, if you have a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyObj>> original` and you want to copy the entire container, duplicating each pointer so that the new `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyObj>> copied` contains pointers to copies of each of the `MyObj` elements from `original`.

Comment: You need to allocate `N` new objects on the heap. Something somewhere will have to call `new` `N` times - no way 'round that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: That makes sense. I hadn't thought of it in that way.

Comment: There is no automatic way to create a deep copy of a `shared_ptr` when it points to a polymorphic type.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, with a foreach, a functor and a virtual clone method.
But before I digged into that, I've found someone who already answered the question in a more modern way (assuming you can use lambdas):
[vector deep copy using a functor or lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212947/vector-deep-copy-using-a-functor-or-lambda)